# Google Datalab - Weird UDF Expansion

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I wanted to refer to an existing UDF from datalab. I have this:

```
%%bq udf --name interpolate -l js
// A function do liner interpolate
// @param lagValue FLOAT64
// @param leadValue FLOAT64
// @param lagReference FLOAT64
// @param leadReference FLOAT64
// @param currentReference FLOAT64
// @returns FLOAT64
// @import gs://myfilehere.js
return interpolate(lagValue, leadValue, lagReference, leadReference, currentReference);
```

The expected expanded SQL should be:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION interpolate (lagValue FLOAT64,leadValue FLOAT64, lagReference FLOAT64,leadReference FLOAT64,currentReference FLOAT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js
AS """
// A function do liner interpolate
// @param lagValue FLOAT64
// @param leadValue FLOAT64
// @param lagReference FLOAT64
// @param leadReference FLOAT64
// @param currentReference FLOAT64
// @returns FLOAT64
// @import gs://myfilehere.js
return interpolate(lagValue, leadValue, lagReference, leadReference, currentReference);
"""
OPTIONS (
library="gs://myfilehere.js"
);
```

However, I got

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION interpolate (lagReference FLOAT64,leadReference FLOAT64,lagValue FLOAT64,leadValue FLOAT64,currentReference FLOAT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js
AS """
// A function do liner interpolate
// @param lagValue FLOAT64
// @param leadValue FLOAT64
// @param lagReference FLOAT64
// @param leadReference FLOAT64
// @param currentReference FLOAT64
// @returns FLOAT64
// @import gs://myfilehere.js
return interpolate(lagValue, leadValue, lagReference, leadReference, currentReference);
"""
OPTIONS (
library="gs://myfilehere.js"
);
```

So, the final UDF parameters order got messed up.  However, I read through the source code, couldn't find anything that actually causes the issue. Need help here.  (I'm with datalab version 1.2.20170525)

**Example here**

definition of my javascript interpolate function:

```
function interpolate(lagValue, leadValue, lagReference, leadReference, currentReference)
{
    if(lagReference==null)
    {
        return leadValue;
    }
    if(leadReference==null)
    {
        return lagValue;
    }    
    if(Math.abs(leadReference-lagReference) > 0)
    {
          return  lagValue + (((currentReference-lagReference)*(leadValue-lagValue))/(leadReference-lagReference));
    }
    else
    {
          return null;
    }
};
```

say I'm gonna call interpolate function in my query:

```
%%bq query  --udfs interpolate
select interpolate(30,20,1,3,2)
```

Here a correct run should be : `lagValue=30, leadValue=20, lagReference=1,leadReference=3, currentReference=2.`

However, when the parameter order got messed up in "CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION" part, this is what actually happening:
`lagValue=1,leadValue=3,lagReference=30,leadReference=20, currentReference=2.` the equation result is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the parameters are extracted into a dictionary, then that dictionary is serialized into a string, which means order is not preserved. Look at https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/blob/master/google/datalab/bigquery/_udf.py#L96.

Is this causing any issues for you? The [BigQuery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) don't say anything about requiring ordered parameters.

Comment: Yes, it did cause me issues. please refer to the example I've just added to my original question.

Comment: I mean, when I used %%bq udf --name interpolate -l js  ,  I wouldn't know in the final parsed UDF definition (by datalab), the parameter order is not same as my '@param' list, so that in my calls, I should have passed lagValue and leadValue in the 3rd and 4th position.   I think datalab should preserve the order as given by user in the '@param' list.

Comment: You're right. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/issues/395.

Comment: This is fixed on Github. You can either wait for the next release to come out, or clone and use the fixed code manually.

Comment: super. when will be the next release?

Comment: You can get a daily build image by pulling gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local-20170605, note however this is not a released build, so use at your own risk.